# Issue with JdbcTemplate batchUpdate

Tags: java, spring, java-8, jdbctemplate

Have a simple requirement where I have to do batchUpdate on List of objects for an update query.

Issue is that after running the code, in database table I see only first row getting updated and rest are not getting updated . Below is the sample code I am using for this.

public void update(List list) {

```
    String sql = "UPDATE table1 \\\r\n"
            + "SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?, modified_on = UTC_TIMESTAMP() \\\r\n"
            + "WHERE col3 = ? \\\r\n"
            + "AND col4 = ? \\\r\n"
            + "AND col5 = ? \\\r\n"
            + "AND col6 = ?" // col5 will be different for different records.

        int[] rowsArray = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            
            
            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return list.size();
            }
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int index) throws SQLException {
                SampleClass sampleClass = list.get(index);
                
                ps.setString(1, sampleClass.getCol1());
                ps.setString(2, sampleClass.getCol2());
                ps.setString(3, sampleClass.getCol3());
                ps.setString(4, sampleClass.getCol4());
                ps.setString(5, sampleClass.getCol5());
                ps.setString(6, sampleClass.getCol6());
                
                
            }
        });
```

}

I can even confirm that setValues() method does get executed N times if my list size is N. But still the batchUpdate gets executed, in DB only first row is updated. I even tried to change the sequence of objects inside list and still the same result. However, if I run JdbcTemplate.update()  method inside the loop for N times for N size list, N records get updated in DB but not with JdbcTemplate.batchUpdat().  I even tried the solution for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate as well but still the same issue. Also, I have the same logic for doing batchUpdates in other Table in the same DB and the this operation is coded in the same code flow. Everything works perfectly fine with that.

Any help on why only first record is getting updated?

Comment: Each record has to be added to a final batch. thats missing in your code. add `ps.addBatch()` that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Each record has to be added to a final batch. that's missing in your code. add `ps.addBatch()` that will solve your problem

```
String sql = "UPDATE table1 \\\r\n"
        + "SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?, modified_on = UTC_TIMESTAMP() \\\r\n"
        + "WHERE col3 = ? \\\r\n"
        + "AND col4 = ? \\\r\n"
        + "AND col5 = ? \\\r\n"
        + "AND col6 = ?" // col5 will be different for different records.

    int[] rowsArray = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        
        
        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return list.size();
        }
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int index) throws SQLException {
            SampleClass sampleClass = list.get(index);
            
            ps.setString(1, sampleClass.getCol1());
            ps.setString(2, sampleClass.getCol2());
            ps.setString(3, sampleClass.getCol3());
            ps.setString(4, sampleClass.getCol4());
            ps.setString(5, sampleClass.getCol5());
            ps.setString(6, sampleClass.getCol6());
            
            ps.addBatch(); // Add this
        }
    });
```